# Gallery stopped working window, after selecting my app for sharing an image

Tags: android

I get a crash window saying

> Unfortunately Gallery has stopped working.

This occurs when I **go to gallery**, **select an image**, **chose share option** and **from the list select my application**.

**Nothing in logcat.**

**Manifest code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imagesharer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagesharer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagesharer.ShareActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagesharer.ImageCaptureActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There will be something in logcat.  Please look again.

Comment: @Simon Sadly now I am not even getting my app in the share-via list. I haven't changed anything :( But previously there was nothing in logcat. The ShareActivity is not even launched.

Comment: add permission of write external storage to ur manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Go to application manager and choose "Turned off" column. Scroll down and find the app "Paper Artist". Turn it on. Should work after that!